ifcopenshell scripting on IFC file loaded in BlenderBIM
I just started exploring BlenderBIM and I was looking if I could directly access the IFC project loaded in Blender through BlenderBIM, to be able to combine the UI from BlenderBIM and scripting whenever needed.
In particular, I want to assign ifc class to 3d objects already loaded in blender through scripting instead of UI. The UI looks like this:


Hello, while there is some overlap between ifcopenshell and BlenderBIM users on this website, you'll have better luck over on the OSArch forum https://community.osarch.org/ or the chat https://app.element.io/#/room/#OSArch:matrix.org cheers
